# Does anyone know what caused this error?

Tags: c#, crash

I made a automail tool in c# for my employer. But it crashed over night. If you need some code or anything please ask and I will provide.

The error:

http://puu.sh/fxyuP/ac05065f22.png

http://puu.sh/fxywx/7008f782ef.png

puu.sh/fxyyn/f47b67d6d4.png

the event log general error:

Faulting application name: DSVODBC APP.exe, version: 1.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x54d34893
Faulting module name: clr.dll, version: 4.0.30319.34014, time stamp: 0x52e0b86c
Exception code: 0xc00000fd
Fault offset: 0x000000000000ba27
Faulting process id: 0x147c
Faulting application start time: 0x01d041eff9cd1cd3
Faulting application path: C:\Users\adm.dominic.bruins\Documents\DSVODBC APP - x64\DSVODBC APP\bin\Debug\DSVODBC APP.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Report Id: 71204741-ade3-11e4-80ce-0050569554b7
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:

Comment: Have you done any debugging?
Also, if you check the event log you will probably find a better error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Source](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2a65c068-4bf7-42ff-94b1-283105d5548d/fatal-errorexception-error-c0000005?forum=visualfoxprogeneral)

> A C0000005 Error is a Windows System error. It is an
>   Exception Error that occurs when a process (application, driver, etc.)
>   tries to execute a processor command that references memory outside
>   the space allocated to that process by the Operating System.
>
> There are many possible causes ranging from corrupt data tables, to a
>   bad network connection, ActiveX controls, or  Printer or Video driver
>   errors. WIthout knowing what type of error you are seeing, it is
>   impossible to guess what the cause may be.

Comment: Thank you. Learned something today. Any suggestions on how to avoid this error in the future?

Comment: @ferdi0314 First try to get the exact cause of this error from the event log. Then we can decide what is the fix

Comment: sure, here is the error from the general tab in the event log: cant add please wait

Comment: Pasted the log in the question description. I would really appriciate your help. @CodingDefined